# How should I handle reloadlessness

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, node.js, express

I'm building an application which are at the moment separated by pages - like any other website. My back-end uses express / handlebars if that's relevant.

I wan't to make the website reload-less across pages. I know I can simply make ajax calls, and replace parts of the page and then change the page URL to simulate a refresh - btw, how would I do this without refreshing, I'd have found this out later but might as well find out now.

Luckily for me, I've built my pages completely modularly using templates, with the base template containing the audio player / headers / js etc - and all pages use this same base.

So I can simply just replace the body and it'll render the same page as what I would've got on a static reload, my problem is how should I route this.
I still want all page's to be statically loadable but then once the user is on their, it become's reloadless

I could make post requests like so `POST - /path` this route would send the raw contents of the page, without the surrounding base.

The the get routes like `GET - /path` which would just be the page inside the base template.

However I have route's that use post request, like login/registration.

Should I use a separate request type strictly for live pages?

I've looked around and seen [these request types](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_methods.htm) `< link`.

I've thought of using `CONNECT`,`HEAD` or `OPTIONS` however they don't seem most appropriate.

The alternative is to use a route like `POST - /live/path` which would be less seamless.

with the post / get solution, I could write an express route like so:

```
app.use("page",function(request, response){
    response.render("page", {
        layout: reqest.method == "post"? null: "default"
    })
}) // I just really like how this works.
```

Another thing is, would I have to manually clear resources when the page is cleared / rewritten, or will browsers automatically handle this?

Comment: you've reached the point where you need a good frontend solution... google for "reactive frontend." ive done this with jquery and angular 1.6 but the new hotness seems to be react-js and angular 2. Hopefully other commenters have more recent experience and better recommendations. Gonna not vote to close as "recommend me a library" since you have clearly stated the problem, what's blocking you, and some code :)

Comment: This question isn't really to do with libraries / I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/193821/are-there-any-problems-with-implementing-custom-http-methods If you don't understand what I was going for - I'll be using a custom HTTP method for my app.